# How to display invoice pdf logo as full size in magento?

Tags: magento, pdf-generation

I have image with dimension of 961*210. I need to display this images in invoice pdf generation in full page(like banner image) on the top of the logo area.

What are the values I need to set for parameters(x1,y1,x2,y2) in `insertLogo()` function?.

```
 $page->drawImage($image, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

I tried multiple values but I can't figured it out. please help me?. I need exact coordinates for full page image (like banner image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah the joys of Zend_Pdf.  The parameters for the drawImage() method are as follows:

- $image = image as created using

  $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($path);

where path is the path to the desired image on the filesystem

- $x1 = distance from the left of the page to the left of the image
- $y1 = distance from the bottom of the page to the bottom of the image
- $x2 = distance from the left of the page to the right of the image
- $y2 = distance from the bottom of the page to the top of the image

Unfortunately working with PDF's is a very manual process, and you are just going to have to try different values until you get it right.  Also remember print margins, you'll want to leave a bit of space for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. finally i got the coordinates. 

$page->drawImage($image, 20, 725, 585, 800);